# Dropping duplicate rows in a Dataframe by column a, while keeping rows that contain values from list in column b

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
     address    issue
row_1   1   No Issue
row_2   1   Value
row_3   1   None
row_4   2   None
row_5   2   Test
row_6   2   None
row_7   3   Example
row_8   4   None
row_9   5   None
row_10  5   None
row_11  5   None
row_12  5   None
row_13  6   No Issue
row_14  6   Example
row_15  6   None
```

Given the above dataframe and I would like to drop duplicates on the "address" column. However, for each duplicate group, I want to keep the row that has an issue column value that is within the below list, dropping the rest.

```
issue_list = ['Value', 'Test', 'Example', 'Sample', 'Signal']
```

If a duplicate group does not have any issue values within the above list (like how address == 5 has all "None" issue values), then the duplicates can be dropped without concern regarding which one is kept, but I do want to keep at least one.

So the desired output dataframe would look like this:

```
     address    issue
row_2   1   Value
row_5   2   Test
row_7   3   Example
row_8   4   None
row_12  5   None
row_14  6   Example
```

I've tried a good number of things so far and I think I'm pretty stuck. It seems like a good option would be to sort the issue column before dropping duplicates, but my problem is that the data is not well maintained, and the "None" issue could be any response(No Issue, No, misspelled) making the alphabetical system unreliable. Moving forward, more issues will be added to the issue_list, so I'm trying to utilize a list of values. I also had a thought to codify the issues into numbers and then sort that way, but before taking that step I figured I would ask here as I feel like there should be a solution. I've tried:

```
df.loc[(df['issue'].isin(issue_list)) | ~df['address'].duplicated(keep=False)]
```

Which returned:

```
    address issue
row_2   1   Value
row_5   2   Test
row_7   3   Example
row_8   4   None
row_14  6   Example
```

Which is close, but it skips address 5 (the one with all "None" issue values). Sorry if this is a duplicate question, I have found a lot of questions surrounding the drop_duplicates function but my situation seems more unique.

Thank you for your time and for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can chunk it into a couple of steps:

Step 1 : Create a boolean for rows that are in the `issue_list`

```
df["issue_isin_list"] = df.issue.isin(issue_list)
```

Step 2 : Create a grouping for each row and get the sum of the newly created boolean columns:

```
df["issue_temp"] = df.groupby("address").issue_isin_list.transform(sum)
```

Step 3:  Create a filter where either `df.issue_isin_list == 1` or `df.issue_temp == 0` :

```
filter_condition = (df.issue_isin_list == 1) | (df.issue_temp == 0)
```

Step 4: Now filter with the condition above, and drop duplicates on the `address` and `issue` columns :

```
df.loc[filter_condition, ["address", "issue"]].drop_duplicates(["address", "issue"])

        address issue
row_2   1   Value
row_5   2   Test
row_7   3   Example
row_8   4   None
row_9   5   None
row_14  6   Example
```